# Browsers close when going to websites

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, firefox, browser, microsoft-edge

I have a desktop computer (specs provided below) that seems to have some kind of odd issue that when some websites are opened, the browser just shuts down completely.

Originally I thought it just an oddity in Google Chrome so had my wife start to use MS Edge or Firefox when a site caused Chrome to shut down.  We quickly found out that some sites, but not all, do not work on any of the browsers.  The list is growing by the day but I have not been able to find any pattern to this.  To add to the mystery, YouTube seems to be the really odd one.  The site opens in all 3 browsers without issue but some videos cause the browsers to shut down but other videos do not.

All Browsers are up-to-date.
Virus scans and Malware scans have been run, nothing found.
I can open the same sites on my laptop without issue, leading me to think it is specific to the desktop.

My last resort (trying to avoid) is to blitz the computer and re-install it fresh unless anyone out there has seen and resolved this issue.

PC Specs:

- Windows 10 Pro x64 (version 20H2 - 19042.630)
- i5-2500 @ 3.30 GHz
- 16 GB Ram
- nVidia GeForce GTX 1050 Ti

Comment: Check the windows event logs and see if there is any relevant info there.

Comment: @kicken That was one of the first places I looked.  I did not see anything specific for Chrome here but I did see an unexpected crash for Edge.  Sadly it really did not help.  Firefox pops up with a 'report this error' but again it really does not help.  With Chrome I was able to enable debug mode and whilst I can see when it crashes, it still does not tell me what actually caused it which means I am no closer to solving it.

Comment: Given that it's a problem across browsers, it hints at there being some sort of system-level issue causing them to crash.  If you have any overclock's applied I'd start by removing those and seeing what happens.  Maybe run a memory test.  If neither helps, then re-format and re-install

Comment: In Firefox, you could check in Browser Console to see what activity might be happening. Also if you "report this error", it might show up in "about:crashes". At the system level, you might run memtest64 to confirm you don't have a memory error that you're running into.

Comment: @user3169, I tried this in Chrome (as well) but the result is the same.  When the browser shuts down, so does the 'console' so I see nothing.  I am unfamiliar with the 'about crashes' and will have a look regarding that.  I am happy to try and run the memtest but I would suspect, if I had bad memory blocks, I would see other programs having issues as well.  This seems to only be effecting browsers.

Comment: You wrote "Firefox pops up with a 'report this error' " . If this was the dialog box after it crashed, then report the error. Then enter 'about:crashes' in the url bar. You should see an entry for it, then check the details. As for memtest64, it's easier that trying to figure out what is using what memory.

Comment: @user3169 Spot on for that, thanks.  It seems this is the Crash Reason EXCEPTION_IN_PAGE_ERROR_READ / STATUS_BAD_COMPRESSION_BUFFER

Comment: How was memtest86? Really reads like a RAM or storage memory problem.